# Array and Associative Array Merge

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-merge

How can I achieve the third array, merging Array1 and Array2?
What's the best way to do that in PHP? Many thanks.
Array2 has like index (key), the associative value of id in Array1.

**Array1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 56
        [grade] => 6.7
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 214
        [grade] => 3.2
    )
)
```

**Array2**

```
Array
(
    [56] => 2.4
    [214] => 5.8 
)
```

**Result wanted**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 56
        [grade] => 2.4
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 214
        [grade] => 5.8
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? One way would be to loop over `Array1`, check if the `id` value is a key/set in `Array2`, and if so replace the `grade` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array1 as &$arrayItem) {
$arrayItem['grade'] = $array2[$arrayItem['id']]
}
```

Here you will have array 1 merged as you wished

Comment: note this will produce `Undefined Error` notices and set the value of `$arrayItem['grade']` to `NULL`  if `$array2[$arrayItem['id']]` is not set.

Comment: That is correct, so there would have to come isset checks.