# PHP Array - Merge Array in a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a computation of boardfeet and I want to store all submitted data from a form to an array. I want to do is when I submit the form the data will be saved in an array the when submitted again the data will be added to the array.

I have an array submitted from a form:

```
  Array
   (
     [0] => Array
     (
        [length] => 5
        [width] => 3
        [height] => 2
     )
    )
```

I want it to merge with this array.:

```
   Array
   (
     [0] => Array
     (
        [length] => 3
        [width] => 3
        [height] => 3
     )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [length] => 5
        [width] => 5
        [height] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [length] => 5
        [width] => 5
        [height] => 5
    )

 )
```

Comment: DID you try anything??

Comment: By any chance did you investigate [php:array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array and Associative Array Merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741689/array-and-associative-array-merge)

Comment: Instead of dumping your question on this forum you should make some effort and show us your code. We're here to point out your mistake, not give away all the answers.

Comment: You can use $_SESSION and array_merge() for this. Set the form submitted data in session every time with array_merge()

Comment: thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$array2[] =   $array1[0];
print_r($array2);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/uAEi0)**

Comment: Please don't entertain such people who are reluctant to make any kind of effort. We are not here to give away all the answers when they are simply going to copy paste without understanding one bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try array_merge function like

```
$merge_array = array_merge($array1,$array2);
print_r($merge_array);
```