# Filling up a smaller array with similar keys with values of a larger array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$arr1 = array('key1' => 'value1' , 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value3'.....,'keyN' => 'valueN');

$arr2 = array('key1' => NULL , 'key5' => NULL, 'key9' => NULL);
```

Is there a quick way to fill up $arr2 with values from $arr1 for each of its keys? $arr2 contains keys which are a subset of the keys of $arr1.

Comment: [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array and Associative Array Merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741689/array-and-associative-array-merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

> returns an array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all the arguments.

```
$arr2 = array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2);
```